# Is the relation decidable?

Tags: computability, algebra

Given an ideal $I$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and P, a polynomial, is it decidable whether $P\in I$?

Comment: How is the ideal given? ​ ​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the Ideal Membership Problem and it is solved using Gröbner bases.

Comment: Thank you, you always give me perfect answer. and I wonder if it may be extended to other closed fields.